# Why does reverse indent enter Hebrew?

Tags: insert-mode

Today I learned that you can use `<C-_>` in insert mode to toggle "Reverse insert" on and off, provided that `:set allowrevins` is set. This sounds like a useful feature (Albeit an obscure and strange feature), so I would like to have it on. However, when I do this, it says

```
-- REVERSE INSERT Hebrew
```

Instead of

```
-- REVERSE INSERT
```

And when I hit

```
i<C-_>Hello World!<esc>
```

Instead of

```
!dlrow olleH
```

Like I would expect, I get

```
!âêøíW íêê÷H
```

Is this the intended feature, or is it a bug?

How can I fix this? I suppose I could just do

```
inoremap <C-_> <C-o>:set ri!<cr>
```

But this seems kinda hacky.I'd prefer to just change some setting. Plus I'm still curious why it goes to Hebrew mode in the first place.

In case it's relevant, this happened with version 7.4.1023 and 7.4.2066, both gvim on windows.

Comment: I think this mode was made specifically for Hebrew input (which is a right to left language).

Comment: Interesting, this does not honor `set encoding`.  i.e. it adds invalid UTF-8 characters if you are in UTF-8.

Comment: Glancing at the source, it looks like the entire "Hebrew mode" was a hack someone made before there was a general right-to-left input mode or unicode (which explains the strange encoding behaviour).